# rendering views in an element instead of the whole body

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The question is pretty simple, it has been answered but i need to do it in a different way.
I'm integrating a Backbone application into my codebase and it is taking over the whole document body.

I can't change the Backbone code, but i need the views to be rendered in a div container of my choice.

Angular does this with:

```
<div ng-view></div>
//or
<ng-view></ng-view>
//or
<div class="ng.view"></div>
```

Does backbone have a soulution for this or will i have to use an iframe?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on the backbone code that you're incorporating. If you have access to non-obfuscated source for it, examine the view implementation.

Comment: thanks. I thought would be something standard as it is in Angular. I found it. Thanks